# JSON Best Practice For Relationships

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express

I am learning nodejs and I have a question about how to structure the relationships of objects. I understand the difference between sql and nosql databases however if I have two collections in my mongoDB database such as :

My dungeon `dungeonSchema` looks like this

```
{
   "name" : "string",
}
```

My item `itemSchema` looks like this

```
{
   "name" : "string",
   "dungeon"  : dungeonSchema
}
```

I have a set of items, and each item is found in a specific dungeon. 
So now say I wanted to add an array of itemSchema items to the dungeon schema to show which ones are contained within it, such as :

```
{
   "name" : "string",
   "items" ; []
}
```

There is obviously going to be no way I can have an array of items that have a property for the dungeon which then in turn has a property for an array of items which each have a property for the dungeon, and so on and so on (which is good because I don't want to overflow), however I was wondering what is the best practice here?

Should I have a different schema for sub items? or is having an empty array ok in this situation? How many levels down is good to go?

I tried to find some information online about this but wasnt really sure what to search for exactly.

Comment: Why would the items need to know about the dungeons? What are you representing here?

Comment: Apologies. I am representing items that are contained in a dungeon. So I would have many dungeons and many items and each item can be found in a specific dungeon.

Comment: So, it seems you have a many-to-one relationship where each dungeon has many items. No need to duplicate the data for which item is where. You'd need to update two values otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If all a dungeon has is name and all its sub-properties are in a different schema, you get a sort of [`anemic domain model`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model)

I dont know what your trying to achieve, but if you are already using a NoSQL database, take advantage of it and do something like

```
dungeon: string,
items: [string]
```

And just add your list of items there.
What you referred to in your description is referencing by id, which is basically a SQL relationship in mongo, I would say go for the above implementation, unless you run into performance issues.

Last but not least, a dungeon can have many items, and a lot of them can be inter related and require transactions to update pieces of the dungeon together or not at all. Rethink your domain business logic and model before jumping to the database implementation, in the end, the db is only a tool.

Comment: BTW, json is just a format, it does not determine models, it is merely used to represent them in a format best understood in multiple environments, your business domain(project requirements) is what determines how your model will look like

Comment: So this would be an array of the item names and not the items themselves? Also I shrank down the dungeon and item models for ease of understanding.

Comment: Yep. It will be one model at first. After you figure out what are your items and their relationships.